# Magento header links missing

Tags: xml, magento, hyperlink

I was working on one of magneto projects. I wanted to add home link adjacent to my account link, I tried changing in the customer.xml file but I couldnt see any changes and reverted back to original code but now my " my account " link is missing can some body tell me what went wrong.

this is my page.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-right.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap.js</name><params/></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/font-awesome.css</stylesheet></action>
                                                                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                                                                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/extra_style.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/grid_1170.css</stylesheet></action>                
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/responsive.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/superfish.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/camera.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
                <label>Page Top</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_header" template="checkout/cart/sidebar_header.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                        <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                    </block>
                </block>

                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links.left" as="topLinksLeft"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="cms/block" name="footer_list">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_list</block_id></action>
                </block>
                <block type="cms/block" name="footer_info">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_info</block_id></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
                <label>Page Bottom</label>
            </block>
        </block>

        <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
    </default>

    <print translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Page -->
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

        </block>
    </print>

     <!-- Custom page layout handles -->
    <page_empty translate="label">
        <label>All Empty Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_empty>

    <page_one_column translate="label">
        <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_one_column>

    <page_two_columns_left translate="label">
        <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_left>

    <page_two_columns_right translate="label">
        <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Right Column)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_right>

    <page_three_columns translate="label">
        <label>All Three-Column Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_three_columns>
</layout>
```

This is my customer.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

Supported layout update handles (action):
- customer_account_index
- customer_address_index
- customer_address_view
- customer_account_login
- customer_account_logoutsuccess
- customer_account_create
- customer_account_forgotpassword
- customer_account_confirmation
- customer_account_edit

Supported layout update handles (special):
- default

-->
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>My Account</label>
                <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
                <title>My Account</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>10</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links.left">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log Out</label>
            <url>customer/account/logout</url>
            <title>Log Out</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare> 
            <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
            <position>100</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="Logout_link"</aParams>
            <beforeText></beforeText>
            <afterText></afterText>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links.left">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log In</label>
            <url>customer/account/login</url>
            <title>Log In</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare> 
            <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
            <position>100</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="Login_link"</aParams>
            <beforeText></beforeText>
            <afterText></afterText>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>

<!--
Layout for customer login page
-->

    <customer_account_login translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

<!--
Layout for customer log out page
-->

    <customer_account_logoutsuccess translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Logout Success</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_logout" template="customer/logout.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_logoutsuccess>

<!--
New customer registration
-->

    <customer_account_create translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

    <customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>

    <customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
        <label>Reset a Password</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_resetpassword>

    <customer_account_confirmation>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Send confirmation link</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="accountConfirmation" template="customer/form/confirmation.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_confirmation>

    <customer_account_edit translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Edit Form</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Edit Account Info</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/form_edit" name="customer_edit" template="customer/form/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
          <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.permanent.callout</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>

<!--
Customer account pages, rendered for all tabs in dashboard
-->

    <customer_account translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
        <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>


        </reference>
    </customer_account>

<!--
Customer account home dashboard layout
-->

    <customer_account_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>

    </customer_account_index>

<!--
Customer account address book
-->

    <customer_address_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Address Book</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_book" name="address_book" template="customer/address/book.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_index>

<!--
Customer account address edit page
-->

    <customer_address_form translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Address Edit Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_form>

</layout>
```

Comment: I think the reference is `<reference name="top.links.left">` not `<reference name="top.links">` in the default section of customer.xml

Comment: Having the same problem, even when reverting to the base/default theme. The top links only say "My Cart" and "Checkout". Furthermore the login page at /index.php/customer/account is blank, not loading any phtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento Header link is not any separate file.
It's display from particular module call for header link.
In Magento Header Links as Below

- My Account
- My Wishlist
- My Cart
- Checkout
- Log In

Hear `My Account` Display from `app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\layout\customer.xml`.

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
</reference>
```

`My Wishlist` Display from `app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\layout\wishlist.xml`.

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
            <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

`My Cart` and `Checkout` Display from `app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\layout\checkout.xml`.

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action> //For My Cart
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action> //For Checkout
            </block>
</reference>
```

`Log In` Display from `app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\layout\customer.xml`.

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Yes, I can see the xml files have these code but still the links arent visble I have given my page.xml code as well

Comment: Hi himansu any help regard hamburger menu thanks, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Answer (score 1):

Magento made some changes during an update.

You have to copy the following over to your theme:

---

Copy:

```
design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml
```

Into:

```
design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/page/template/links.phtml
```

---

Copy:

```
design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/linksblock.phtml
```

Into:

```
design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/page/template/linksblock.phtml
```

---

Copy:

```
design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist
```

Into:

```
design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/wishlist
```

---

Copy:

```
design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml
```

Into:

```
design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout/wishlist.xml
```

Clear your caches and all should be good!

Comment: Thank you. This somehow seemed to be te problem :)